# Does <ClassName> perform casting in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

The [angular DI](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#!#token) documentation has the following example:

```
let mockService = <HeroService> {getHeroes: () => expectedHeroes }
```

Is `mockService` now an instance of `HeroService`?

Here is another code snippet in case that helps make it clearer:

```
it('should have heroes when HeroListComponent created', () => {
  let hlc = new HeroListComponent(mockService);
  expect(hlc.heroes.length).toEqual(expectedHeroes.length);
});
```

I think `mockService` has to be an instance of the `HeroService` implementation or interface, because the `HeroListComponent` expects such an instance it the constructor.

Comment: what do you mean by instance? as in `prototype` instance? Typecasting has no effect on runtime

Comment: update the post with more code

Comment: TypeScript does not have "casting". It has "type assertions". You are asserting that the `{}` object is of type `HeroService`. Such assertions will fail if the assertion cannot be applied--if the value is not compatible with the type being asserted. `mockService` will be considered to be of type `HeroService`, but that is distinct from it being an instance of some class `HeroService`.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm not sure that it's a true statement that "TypeScript does not have casting", as it states in the docs: "A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data".

Comment: @Nitzan Right, it's **sort of like** a type cast, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not an instance of `HeroService`.
Let's see a simple example:

```
class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    toString() {
        return `(${this.x}, ${this.y})`;
    }
}

let a = <Point>{ x: 0, y: 0 };
```

Here `a` isn't an instance of `Point`, it just has the same members, but if you'll do `console.log(a.toString)` you'll get `[object Object]` instead of `(0, 0)`.

You can read more about this here: [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), and also you might want to check out this: [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

Comment: I think after typecasting the compiler treats `a` as in instance of `Point` class and verifies it has the methods specific to the Point class. `let a = <Point>{x: 0, y: 0, go() {}}; a.go();` gives an error - `Property 'go' does not exist on type 'Point'.` although the method exists on `a`

Comment: @Maximus This is not different than in other languages, it's just polymorphism.